# How can I continue to operate the gdb command console?

Tags: debugging, gdb

Maybe a simple question.

When I attach to a process, I run "continue" to make it continue to run.

Then I want to some other job like "add-symbol-file" with need not interactive with target process, but after the "continue" command, the gdb console will block, so I can not do any action before I break the process.

Is there any way that I can do such thing without suspend the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until recently you couldn't do what you want, but the newly released
version 7.0 of gdb has what is called a "non-stop" mode, in which the
gdb prompt / console can be used while the program is running.

See http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_6.html#SEC47

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the console which gdb is running in has keyboard focus, then press CTRL-C. This will usually result in a SIGINT signal to be sent to gdb.
With me, GDB then pauses execution of the program and accepts user commands again.

Should the CTRL-C not work (perhaps different config) try to send the signal manually:
Find out the pid of gdb such as with command *top* and then send a SIGINT to gdb:

```
kill -2 pidhere
```

Comment: better to use the symbolic name, `kill -INT pid`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to study the [remote gdb mechanisms](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_232.html) a bit for something like that.
For understanding the debugging process more [read this short article](http://www.alexonlinux.com/how-debugger-works).